# react + fetch выдают "POST <сервер> 401 (Unauthorized)"

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

Подскажите как побороть следующую проблему:

посылаю ajax-запрос с помощью `fetch` на локальный сервер, для того чтобы браузер не выдавал ошибки про CORS использую `mode: 'no-cors'`

получается такой код:

```
componentDidMount() {
   
      async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {

      const response = await fetch(url, {
            method:         'POST',
            mode:           'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body:           JSON.stringify(data) 
        });

        return await response;
    }

    postData(myserver, { mydata: myvalue })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Но на выходе я получаю

```
index.tsx:41 POST мой_сервер 401 (Unauthorized)
index.tsx:54 Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
```

при этом если на сервер посылаю запрос просто через командую строку браузера, то сервер нормально отвечает.

Подскажите в чем может быть дело и как можно заставить сервер ответить на запрос.

**P.S.**

решил проблему через атрибуты запуска браузера

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/ChromeDevSession"
```

но как по мне - это костыль и хотелось бы решение, осуществляемое силами сайта, если такое возможно

Comment: А токен Вы как передаёте?

Comment: « для того чтобы браузер не выдавал ошибки про CORS использую mode: 'no-cors'» — фейспалм. Неужели сложно прочитать документацию и обнаружить что в этом режиме браузер не посылает *никаких* авторизационных заголовков (в частности никаких кук)

Comment: @Alexey Ten, почитал уже и разобрался, можете убирать от лица ладонь :) но вопрос тогда остается - как общаться с сервером. Решил проблему через атрибуты запуска Chrome - но как по мне - это костылинг, потому что все хотелось бы делать в рамках сайта

Comment: Научить «мой_сервер» отдавать правильные заголовки `Access-Control-…` Информации по настройке CORS в сети куча.

Comment: На чем основан API вашего сервера?  nodejs, express, php, laravel, java / spring boot?

Comment: @Ajeet Shah, php